# Filter on SQL As varialble

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have following query. How can I use the SQL variable `is_followed` (which is true or false) in where clause ?
Or How can I only get those records where subquery `is_followed` is true.

```
scoped = User.select(<<-SQL
      DISTINCT(users.*),
      EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM followers
        WHERE
          followers.follower_id=#{current_user.id} AND
          followers.active=true
      ) AS is_following,
    SQL
    .squish)
```

I wanted to use the `is_followed` variable further in the next queries. Something like as follow

`scoped.where(is_following: true)`

I know I can do `scoped.select(&:is_following)` but I wanted to use it in SQL

Regards

Comment: you can't use 'is_followed' this way because you are specifying it as a alias and this doesn't store a boolean value

Comment: @vkp I think there might be a way for this, as when I check scoped.first.attributes it contain is_followed variable

Comment: Also If I am dam sure that I can use it in SQL clause